# PM Intern as a compsci student?

Tags: resume, computer-science

I'm a second year CompSci student based in the UK hoping to get a career as a software developer.

I've been offered a Project Management internship in an online banking company. I don’t have much experience on my cv so I don’t want to be picky with my first internship but I was just wondering if being a PM intern in a digital focused company would still help translate to a software engineering job in the future?

The time commitment would be around 3 months, so I’m not sure if I would be using the most of my time by taking this internship.

Should I still take it or should I look for a software engineer internship but risk losing my previous offer?

Answer (score 2):

> i was just wondering if being a PM intern in a digital focused company would still help translate to a software engineering job in the future

No. If you want to be a software engineer, find a software engineering internship.

Comment: Ofcourse a software engineering internship is ideal, but if i turn down this guaranteed position i might be risking not having an internship this summer and i really need it. Does an IT PM internship provide no transferrable skills in a software engineering job?

Comment: It's professional work experience which will help you develop your soft skills, but as a hiring manager I'd discount it entirely in terms of your software engineering skills.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, With that said, as a second year Comp Sci student, he's unlikely to get a software engineer internship (unless he's really good at programming already). So if it's a choice between unemployment this summer and this position, he should take this position I think.

Answer (score 2):

While obviously a relevant job is slightly better, you're a second year student. No one particularly cares if you had a gig as a waiter or a dev intern. Either way it proves you can actually get up in the morning and do some work without embarrassing yourself too much. Which is extremely important in most workplaces.

Answer (score 1):

Gaining project management experience can only be helpful to your eventual career as a software engineer. Understanding the project lifecycle outside of the scope of development will help you better understand how your work as a developer fits into the bigger picture. If it were me, I'd accept the project management internship.

Answer (score -3):

It is not software development, but having a three month internship in a Project Management role will make you a lot more valuable even for a software development role. It's basically looking at the exact same problems from another point of view; I would say that is a valuable experience. (And I disagree with Philip Kendall's comment there who says quite the opposite. So you are a bit on your own, but nobody will disagree that this internship is much much better than no internship at all).

Comment: It might be valuable experience for growing as a software developer, but it isn't for *finding a job as a software developer* which is what OP wants to do. If a received a CV with no actual development experience, only product manager experience, I wouldn't be inclined to consider them for a software development job.